# Access SQL Query for All Records (non-zero)

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
Date        Name    Charge
1/15/2015   Alpha   3.39
2/15/2015   Alpha   3.39
2/15/2015   Beta    3.39
2/15/2015   Gamma   2
3/15/2015   Gamma   3
3/15/2015   Alpha   5
4/15/2015   Beta    3.39
```

Above is a sample table in Access. My intent is to capture all unique Names that have strictly value 3.39 for 'Charge', but if any name has a value other than 3.39, then the query would not return the Name at all. For example, based on sample data, a correctly write query would result in only "Beta" showing up.

How can a SQL query be written for the above requirements?

Comment: Next time you post a SQL question, please post the query that [you've already tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: @sigil This is what I tried beforehand, and am still not getting the correct query based on both answers below: 'PARAMETERS [Start Date] DateTime, [End Date] DateTime;
    SELECT [myTable].[Name]
    FROM [myTable]
'WHERE ([myTable].[Invc Date] >= [Start Date] AND [myTable].[Invc Date] <= [End Date])
'GROUP BY [myTable].[Name]
'HAVING SUM([myTable].[Charge])=0;

Comment: That query is quite different from what you asked in this question--that's a parameter query looking for records that fall within the `Start Date` - `End Date` range whose `Charge` values add up to 0.

Comment: There are two "Beta"s with 3.39 charge in your data. How does that translate into only 1 "Beta" in the result and yet not apply to "Alpha" also?

Comment: The intent is to capture unique names that have strictly charges of 3.39. I've done the same for charges strictly equal to 0 through the following code, but am looking for something similar for 3.39:

Comment: PARAMETERS [Start Date] DateTime, [End Date] DateTime;
    SELECT [myTable].[Name]
    FROM [myTable]
    WHERE ([myTable].[Date] >= [Start Date] AND [myTable].[Date] <=     [End Date])
    GROUP BY [myTable].[Name]
    HAVING SUM([myTable].[Charge])=0;

Answer (score 1):

Well I got beat to the answer, but here's another way:

```
SELECT [Name] FROM dbo.charges
WHERE [Charge] = '3.39'
GROUP BY [Name]
HAVING [Name] NOT IN (
    SELECT [Name] FROM dbo.charges
    WHERE [Charge] <> '3.39'
    GROUP BY [Name]
)
```

Okay, that was the SQL Server version, here is the very slightly different Access version:

```
SELECT [Name] FROM charges
WHERE [Charge] = 3.39
GROUP BY [Name]
HAVING [Name] NOT IN (
    SELECT [Name] FROM charges
    WHERE [Charge] <> 3.39
    GROUP BY [Name]
)
```

The table name here is "charges" - change the table and field names to your table and field names, although based on the above conversation I'm not sure if this is what you need any more.

Here is an update with the parameters added:

```
PARAMETERS [Start Date] DateTime, [End Date] DateTime; 
SELECT charges.Name
FROM charges
WHERE (((charges.Date)>=[Start Date] And (charges.Date)<=[End Date]) AND ((charges.Charge)=3.39))
GROUP BY charges.Name
HAVING (((charges.Name) Not In (SELECT [charges].[Name] FROM [charges] WHERE [charges].[Charge] <> 3.39 GROUP BY [charges].[Name])));
```

Comment: What's dbo.charges? I'm assuming it's my actual table name. Upon using the table name, Access returns back error indicating the expression is too complicated. Keep in mind that my query also includes date criteria as parameters

Comment: Oh sorry, that is a SQL Server query, probably won't work in a native Access database.  Got ahead of myself and forgot to check what database you were using.

Comment: `PARAMETERS [Start Date] DateTime, [End Date] DateTime;     SELECT [charges].[Name]    FROM [charges]    WHERE ([charges].[Invc Date] >= [Start Date] AND [charges].[Invc Date] <= [End Date] AND [charges].[Charge] <> 3.39)'
`GROUP BY [charges].[Name]'
`HAVING [charges].[Name] NOT IN ('
` SELECT [charges].[Name] FROM [charges]'
` WHERE [charges].[Charge] <> 3.39'
` GROUP BY [charges].[Name]'
`);'
Hi @PhillipXT and @sigil - The above is what I tried by using your input & adding more criteria for date range (using Parameters), but query isn't returning any results, when results are expected

Comment: @stitch70, to test, can you try just this query by itself: `SELECT [Name] FROM charges WHERE [Charge] <> 3.39 GROUP BY [Name]`.  That should give you a list of all the unique names that have a `Charge` value other than 3.39.  If that doesn't work, the problem may be with the data format.

Comment: Also, what values are you using for [Start Date] and [End Date]?

Comment: It looks like you have a <> where you need a = on the first Charge comparison.  See my updated answer for another version of the query with parameters added.

Comment: The `SELECT [Name] FROM charges WHERE [Charge] <> 3.39 GROUP BY [Name]` query worked fine. But when applying the updated query above with the PARAMETERS and the updated fix from <> to =, the query still results in lower # of results than expected. When changing value to 5, query results in no results. The query works fine when changing value to 0. The values for [Start Date] and [End Date] are in mm/dd/yyyy upon input entry. As an alternate, it seems both of you were able to use the  s1 & s2 solution successfully. How would I apply that solution natively into an Access query without using VBA?

Comment: I ask because the query with s1 & s2 returns zero results as well

Comment: If you change the value to 5, it should return 0 results.  The only entry with a 5 is "alpha", which also has entries with other values, so it will be excluded.

Comment: @stitch70, to create a SQL query in Access (i'm using Access 2010): create a new query with Query Design, right-click on the tab with the name of the query, select SQL View, enter the SQL query, then click Run.

Comment: @stitch70, if you mean, "how do I use the `s1` and `s2` aliases?", I've already written them in the SQL statement as they should be for aliasing.  You'll need to change `thisTable` to the name of your table, of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct Name from thisTable s1
left join
(select * from thisTable where Charge<>3.39) s2
on
s1.Name=s2.Name
where
s2.Name is null
and
s1.Charge=3.39
```

Comment: `s1` and `s2` are the aliases of `thisTable` and the nested `Charge<>3.39` query.

Comment: This query worked for me (well, it produced the same results as mine below - not sure if either solve the problem here), I just had to make a small change to say `select distinct s1.Name`.

Comment: I've went ahead and used: "SELECT Name FROM tbl 
GROUP BY Name HAVING AVG(Charge) = 3.39"